# When to use polar substitution?

Tags: limits, partial-differential-equations, continuity, substitution

I have solved the problem below, which gave me this question: How do i know when to use polar substitution?

If, instead of polar substitution, I directly set (x, y) = (0,0), I get division by zero. Therefore, I will instead use polar substitution. Is there anything else I should think about?

The problem. 
*How can the funtion be defined at the origin so that it becoms continuous at all points of the xy-plane?*
$$f(x,y) = \frac{x^2+y^2-x^3y^3}{x^2+y^2}, \ (x,y)\neq(0,0)$$

My solution.
$$\text{Polar substitution: } x=r\cos\theta,\ y=r\sin\theta,\ x^2+y^2=r^2\\
\begin{align}
&\lim_{r\to0}\frac{r^2-r^3\cos^3\theta\, r^3\sin^3\theta}{r^2}\\
&\Rightarrow\lim_{r\to0} \frac{r^2(1-r\cos^3\theta\, r^3\sin^3\theta r)}{r^2(1)}\\
&\Rightarrow\lim_{r\rightarrow0} \frac{r^2(1-r\cos^3\theta\, r^3\sin^3\theta)}{r^2(1)}\\
&\Rightarrow\lim_{r\rightarrow0} \frac{1-r\cos^3\theta\, r^3\sin^3\theta}{1}\\
&\Rightarrow\lim_{r\rightarrow0} \frac{1-0\cos^3\theta\, 0^3\sin^3\theta}{1} \Rightarrow f(0,0)=1\\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: You can use polar substitution to show the function is discontinuous at the origin. But to use polar substitution to prove it continuous, you really have to be careful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the polar substitution bounds the function between functions of $r$ that have the same limit, you can prove the intermediate function has the same limit by the squeeze theorem. In this case,$$f=1-r^4\cos^3\theta\sin^3\theta=1-\tfrac18r^4\sin^32\theta$$is bound between $1\mp\tfrac18r^4$. But even the looser, more obvious bounds $1\mp r^4$ prove the limit is $1$.